# Finding Kp at another temp with /\Hrxn

Tags: equilibrium, concentration, vapor-pressure

Took a pic of the paper I tried it on it on, has the exact problem description written at top, and what I tried. Figured that would be easier then typing all that. The answer is supposed to be 2.0.

[image]

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking. Do you want us to check your calculation? It might be easier for you to just take a picture and post it here, but it is much harder for everybody else. Also this way, this is not helping anyone how looks for a solution of a similar problem. Please consider the users helping out here are doing this in their free time (just for fun and giggles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the wrong version of $R$.  Try using $R = 8.314 J mol^{-1} \ K^{-1}$.